# python socket : sending file between two computers

Tags: python, sockets

i am trying to download a file between two computers. server side computer will download file and client side computer will send file to server side computer. i wrote below codes to achieve this scenario but somethings went wrong. what is the wrong with below codes.

```
# server
import socket
import os

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(("10.0.2.15", 5555))
s.listen(100)
c, addr = s.accept()
def save_file(file_name):
    while 1:
        c.send(file_name.encode())
        confirmation = c.recv(1024).decode()
        if confirmation == "file-doesn't-exist":
            print("File doesn't exist on server.")
        else:
            write_name = file_name[9:]
            with open(write_name, 'wb') as _file:
                while 1:
                    data = c.recv(1024)
                    if not data:
                        break
                    file.write(data)
            return '[+] ' + write_name + ' successfully downloaded.'

def run():
    while 1:
        data = ""
        cmd = raw_input('command>> ')
        if cmd[:8] == "download":
            data = save_file(cmd)
        print(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

```
#client
import socket
import os
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect("10.0.2.15", 5555)
def send_file(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        s.send("file-doesn't-exist".encode())
    else:
        s.send("file-exists".encode())
        if path != "":
            _file = open(path, "rb")
            path = _file.read(1024)
            while path:
                s.send(path)
                path = _file.read(1024)
def run():
    command = s.recv(1024).decode()
    if command[:8] == "download":
        s.send(command[9:])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Most of your code is irrelevant to the problem. You could probably reproduce the problem with 5 lines of code.

Comment: i can not explain and generalize this code with 5 lines. it is already shortened version.

Comment: TCP streams aren't message-oriented. Your client sends `file-exists` immediately followed by the data of the file, and your server reads (up to!) 1024 bytes, which may (likely _will_) be something like `file-existsJPEGBINARYDATAHEREetcetc...`. You'll need to come up with a message encapsulation scheme.

Comment: Also, you need to use `s.sendall()` if you want to be sure all of the data you pass in is actually sent.